# Exce: Refer to the cell one row below address in another cell

Tags: excel

I would welcome some help with my problem. I have three cells:

```
A1
="API!"&Overview!B5
Both "API!" and "Overview" are names of sheets.
This cell gives me the following address(string): API!C2

B1
= INDIRECT(A1)

B2
= ?
```

I would like in this cell the formula that retrieves the data in the cell one row below API!C2, namely API!C3

Does anyone have any idea how I can retrieve this particular cell reference?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OFFSET:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1),1,0)
```